# SUMPRODUCT if cells within range contains a string

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to have SUMPRODUCT to sum values "if cells within range contain a certain piece of string"?

[image]

PS: it has to be a string since letters are actually names and words from the actual report.

Maybe a combination between SUMPRODUCT and SEARCH, but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only one column use SUMIF() with a wildcard:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*" & D2 & "*",B:B)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

If you are worried about false positive as @YowE3k stated:

> a `SUMIF(A:A,"*BERT*",B:B)` will count the values for Bert, Robert, and Roberta.

You will need to limit the reference to only the data set and use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" " & D2 & " "," " & $A$2:$A$6 & " "))*$B$2:$B$6)
```

Comment: @clickhere are you asking a question or making a statement?

Comment: Oh, sorry, your image wasn't coming through, seeing it now, was just trying to help you by adding a visual aid.

Comment: Thank you so much @ScottCraner ! So simple, yet lovely! Thanks :D

Comment: One thing to be wary of (having just seen the OP's previous question), a `SUMIF(A:A,"*BERT*",B:B)` will count the values for Bert, Robert, and Roberta.

Comment: Nice observation @YowE3K. I'm guessing that if I add a space after and before the asterisks like "* BERT *", the formula would only look for full words, right?

Comment: @SoMeGoD yes and no, if you add a space before and after then it will skip the first and the last unless you manually put a space before and after the string of names in the cells.  If you want to do that it will require SUMPRODUCT which is more calculation intensive.

Comment: @SoMeGoD - If you could include an extra column (which is set as `=" "&A2&" "` etc) then you could probably go back to the simpler `=SUMIF(X:X,"* " & D2 & " *",B:B)` (assuming new column is column X) - it's a tradeoff between having the extra column or using the more complicated formula.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely need the first and last names (no space before and no space ater). Since I'm trying to automate this by vba, I think I will do a concatenate to add space before/after for the whole cell @YowE3K Thanks for that.